# Building a map from a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, matrix, mapping

I have a matrix A which holds integers in a bounded range (0..255) and I need to build a table mapping a value (0..255) to all the coordinates in the matrix which hold this value.

What is the best way to achieve this? - I thought about using containers.Map for the task but Map doesn't support multiple values per key. I could have used lists but that would seem inefficient as I would have to create a new list on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized solution, which gives the same output as [the solution from Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279385/building-a-map-from-a-matrix-in-matlab/3279750#3279750), is to sort all the pixel values in your image using the [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) function, convert the linear indices returned from [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) into subscripted indices using the function [IND2SUB](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ind2sub.html), and collect them together into a single cell array using the functions [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) and [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
A = randi([0 255],[5 5],'uint8');         %# A sample matrix
[values,indices] = sort(double(A(:)));    %# Sort all the pixel values
[y,x] = ind2sub(size(A),indices);         %# Convert linear index to subscript
counts = accumarray(values+1,1,[256 1]);  %# Count number of each value
map = mat2cell([y x],counts);             %# Create a 256-by-1 cell array
```

Now, for a given integer value `iValue` you can get the `N`-by-2 matrix containing the `y` (first column) and `x` (second column) coordinates for the `N` pixels in the image with that value by doing the following:

```
key = double(iValue)+1;  %# Need to use double to avoid integer saturation
points = map{key};       %# An N-by-2 coordinate matrix
```

In addition, just in case you're interested, you could also make `map` a structure array with fields `x` and `y` using the function [STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html):

```
map = struct('x',mat2cell(x,counts),'y',mat2cell(y,counts));
```

And you can then access the `x` and `y` coordinates for pixels with a value `iValue` as follows:

```
key = double(iValue)+1;
x = map(key).x;
y = map(key).y
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a cell array? You can index it with integers. For example:

```
map = {[1,1;13,56], [], [4,5]};
```

In this example index 0 is in the matrix in `1,1` and `13,56`, index 1 in none and index 2 in `4,5`

Your cell would have 256 elements (mine has 3) and to acces you would simply add 1 to the index.

You could also store indices linearly so the code to fill the table would be:

```
for ii = 0:255
    map{ii+1} = find( mat(:)==ii )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wrote the following and it seems to work in reasonable time. I think the thing that does the trick is preallocating the cell arrays based on the histogram for each value:

```
[H, W] = size(A);
histogram = hist(A, 256);
AGT = arrayfun(@(avg) {0 cell(1, histogram(avg))}, 1:256, 'UniformOutput', false);
for y = 1:H
    for x = 1:W
        idx = A(y, x) + 1;
        count = AGT{idx}{1};
        AGT{idx}{2}{count + 1} =  [y x];
        AGT{idx}{1} = count + 1;
    end
end
```

Accessing the table is a bit annoyting though :

```
AGT{200}{2}{:}
```

to access all coordinates with value 200.